# Yeraeh el HaAdon, or Yeraeh es HaAdon

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, grammar-dikduk, parashat-ki-tisa, shalosh-regalim

The *mitzvah* of *aliya leregel*, the thrice-yearly pilgrimage festival, appears a few times in the Torah.

In Exodus 23:17 it's written:

> שָׁלֹ֥שׁ פְּעָמִ֖ים בַּשָּׁנָ֑ה יֵרָאֶה֙ כָּל־זְכ֣וּרְךָ֔ **אֶל**־פְּנֵ֖י הָאָדֹ֥ן וגו

However, in Exodus 34:23 it's written:

> שָׁלֹ֥שׁ פְּעָמִ֖ים בַּשָּׁנָ֑ה יֵרָאֶה֙ כָּל־זְכ֣וּרְךָ֔ **אֶת**־פְּנֵ֛י הָֽאָדֹ֥ן וגו

I understand the first way it is written. Three times a year all your males shall be seen to the Master...

However, the second way, instead of the Hebrew אל, it uses את, which doesn't have an English translation, but is used as a pointer towards a object of a verb. However, I'm not familiar with את being used with passive verbs, such as יראה of this verse.

1. How exactly is את meant to be understood in the second verse, or it is simply the same as the first
2. Do any commentaries explain why the change in word usage?

Comment: Also the last pasuk in Reeh says את

Answer (score 1):

[R. Samuel David Luzzato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_David_Luzzatto) in his commentary to Isaiah 1:12 explains that the verses describing the pilgrimage were meant to be vowelized such that they would mean that the people come to see God, but the Masoretes (based on a tradition going back to the Second Temple Sages) "fixed" them so that the fools who can't understand the real meaning wouldn't think that you can actually see God's face.

He cites three lines of evidence for this, the second of which is that the Torah always says את פני or פני except for one time where it says אל פני, and even in that instance according to the testimony of Kennicott there are variant texts which have את there too, as does the Samaritan Pentateuch.

> כוונת הנביא לומר לִרְאוֹת פני והיא מליצה דרך משל כאדם המקביל פני רבו כמליצת כי על כן ראיתי פניך כראות פני אלהים (בראשית ל”ג:י’) אפס בעלי הנקוד (לפי קבלה שהיתה בידם מחכמי בית שני) תקנו הלשון דרך כבוד מפני ההדיוטות שלא היו מבינים משל ומליצה (וכדרך שעשה אנקלוס בתרגומו וכן כאן תרגם יונתן לאתחזאה קדמי) להרחיק הגשמות שלא יהיה נראה כאלו האדם רואה פני האלהים וכן מתי אבא ואראה פני אלהים (תהלים מ”ב:ג’) כוונת המשורר לומר וְאֶרְאֶה וכן בעלותך לראות את פני ה’ אלהיך (שמות ל”ד:כ”ד) עִקר הכוונה הוא לִרְאוֹת ודברי אלה יתלבנו ויתבררו אם תסתכל במה שאומר ראשונה לא מצאנו בשום מקום מליצת נראה לפני ה’ אבל בכל מקום את פני ה’ או פני ה’ זולתי פעם אחת מצאנו יראה כל זכורך אל פני האדון ה’ (שמות כ”ג:י”ז) וגם שם נמצא בקצת ספרים (בעדות קניקוט) את פני וכן בחומש שמרוני שנית בפסוק ולא יראו פני ריקם (שמות כ”ג:ט”ו) הדבר ברור כי פני ה’ הם הנראים והאדם הוא הרואה ואין לפרש ולא יֵרָאוּ לפני כי בכל משך הפרשה ההיא מן כי תקנה עבד עברי (כ”א:ב’) מדובר עם אנשי ישראל לנכח ולא לנסתר ושלישית בכל מקום שהכוונה התגלות דבר מה זולתי האל יתברך מצאנו תמיד לְהֵרָאוֹת בה”א אחר הלמ”ד הלא תראה כי לא יוכלו להראות לבא העירה (שמואל ב י”ז:י”ז) וילך אליהו להראות אל אחאב (מלכים א י”ח:ב’) להראות חטאותיכם (יחזקאל כ”א:כ”ט) וכן כשהכוונה על גלוי השכינה או גלוי המלאך מצאנו תמיד הה”א אחר הלמ”ד ולא יסף עוד מלאך ה’ להראה אל מנוח (שופטים י”ג:כ”א) ויוסף ה’ להראה בשילה (שמואל א ג’:כ”א) ובהפך בכל מקום שהכוונה על ביאת המקדש מצאנו תמיד לראות בלא ה”א כמו כאן ובשמות ל”ד:כ”ד וכן בבא כל ישראל לראות את פני ה’ אלהיך (דברים ל”א:י”א) ומה שכתוב ונראה את פני ה’ (שמואל א א’:כ”ב) גם שם היתה דעת הכותב לומר בבנין הקל וְנִרְאֶה עתיד למדברים בעדם כלומר כשנלך כלנו לראות את פני ה’ אז הנער ישב שם עד עולם

Thus, according to this, the verse with את is the understandable one while the verse with אל is either some kind of lone aberration or a scribal error.

Answer (score 0):

The Netziv in Haamek Davar Exodus 34:23 addresses this question. I believe it addresses both parts of the question:

את פני. ושם כתיב אל פני. דשם מיירי בשש שני עבודה והמון ישראל רחוקים ממנו ית׳ ובאים ברגל אל ה׳. אבל בשביעית גם בלי רגל כל איש ישראל אינו רחוק במחשבתו מעבודתו באשר הוא פנוי וכמש״כ לעיל כ״א. מש״ה ברגלים בא להוסיף דביקות ואהבת ה׳ מש״ה כתיב את פני. שהאדם עומד אתו כ״י:

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll upvote this if you translate it. Also would be helpful if you clarify how he knows the verse in Ki Sisa is about shmitta. I assume he knows from two verses earlier.